# Force same line spacing despite changing font size in some words or symbols

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

I am trying to use the quote environment to start with a larger "quotes" symbol. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\def\relat#1{
\begin{quote}
    \setstretch{1}
    \fontfamily{phv} \selectfont 
        \hspace*{-0.40cm}\raisebox{-1.2ex}{\huge \textbf{``}}{#1}
\end{quote} }
\renewenvironment{quote}
{\small\list{}{\rightmargin=0.25cm \leftmargin=1cm}%
    \item\relax}
{\endlist}

\begin{document}
MNExample

\relat{Não se pode afirmar que, a julgar pela amostra sob estudo, os cidadãos têm uma opinião positiva sobre a importância do parlamento europeu para dar voz aos cidadãos (\textit{W}=32, \textit{p}=0.555).} 

But then ...

    
\end{document}
```

I get the desired effect, but the first line has a larger spacing then the other following lines:

[image]

using package `setspace` and `\setstrech{1}` should force the line spacing,... but it does not, and I am clueless why?

Any ideas on how to force the same line spacing? Thanks!

Comment: Try to place the enlarged quotation mark inside `\smash{...}`.

Comment: no, it does the same.... :-(

Comment: The idea is essentially to place everything that extends over the surrounding line height or below it inside a box with the height of zero. So, make sure that the complete `\raisebox` is inside the `\smash`.

Comment: Ah, ok!... that works! Thanks !